# Why is dual functor continuous?

Tags: derived-functors

Recall that a functor F is continuous is the map from Hom(V，W）to Hom(F(V),F(W)) is always continuous. I have already know how to prove the functor V** is continuous, but don't know why the functor F(V)=V* is continuous. Please give some advice about that.

Comment: Hint: Fix a basis, and ask your self what the entries of $T^\ast$ are in terms of the entries of $T$. It should be pretty obvious then.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks.